# Handlebars.net: Reached end of template before block expression 'currency' was closed

Tags: handlebars.net

I have a template that looks like this:
(I removed some elements of the table just to keep the code short)

```html
              {{#each Tables}}
              <div id='report-container'>
                <table id='report-table'>
                  <tr class='header-row'>
                    <th style='width: 150px; max-width: 150px !important;'>{{this.Title}}</th>
                    <th>Total Company Net Sales $</th>
                    ...
                  </tr>
    
                  {{#each this.Data}}   
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{RowTitle}}</td>
                    <td>{{currency TotalCompanyNetSales}}</td>
                    ...
                  </tr>
                  {{/each}}

                </table>
              </div>
              {{/each}}
```

With a helper:

```
        handleBars.RegisterHelper("currency", (writer, context, parameters) =>
        {
            var value = decimal.Parse(parameters[0].ToString());
            value /= 1000;
            var result = value.ToString("0,-28:C2");
            return result;
        });
```

Im not sure if the object itself is relevant but I can post if necessary. The problem is just with the helper. When I try to compile the template I get the following error message:

"Reached end of template before block expression 'currency' was closed"

If I remove the currency helper the value displays fine. It never even calls the currency function. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is related to a misuse of new *(to Handlebars.Net)* `return helper` syntax: helper you're declaring is actually a `block` helper returning value:

```cs
handleBars.RegisterHelper("currency", (writer /*this is not `writer` but `options`*/, context, parameters) =>
{
    // your code here
    return result; // change is caused by the `return` statement
});
```

In order to fix the helper and still use `return` feature you should simply drop the `options` argument from lambda:

```cs
handleBars.RegisterHelper("currency", (context, parameters) =>
{
    // your code here
    return result;
});
```

Comment: Wow. I am not sure how I missed that. Thank you!